# Writing XML filenames from folder in CSV in Python

Tags: python, xml, csv, file

I have folder `C:\test_xml` where i have list of `XML` files. I want to get all the xml file names and store this in csv file `xml_file.csv`. I am trying with below Python code but dont know how to proceed as i am quiet new in Python.

```
import os
import glob

files = list(glob.glob(os.path.join('C:\temp','*.xml')))
print (files)
```

Comment: try `r'C:\temp'` instead of `'C:\temp'`, this is `C:` then a tabstop, then `emp`. Or `'C:\\temp'`

Comment: it returns the complete file path with xml filename now...it should return only filename and how to save this in csv file ?

Answer (score 0):

A way to get a list of only the filenames:

```py
import pathlib
files = [file.name for file in pathlib.Path(r"C:\temp").glob("*.xml")]
```

The [documentation for the csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) has some examples on how to write a .csv file

Comment: thanks it prints now the file name...but how can i save those in csv file ? i checked the document but dont know how to pass this parameter